# configuring language in Bootstrap Date Range Picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker

I am using the Bootstrap Date Range Picker provided and explained [In this page](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage) I added all the library using the cdn, I mean this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

But the thing is that I need all in spanish and I don´t see a piece of code to configurate it. How should I do it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Include the `locale` option and edit the appropriate strings, like `fromLabel` or `December` :

```js
$('#datePicker').daterangepicker({
    "locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Su",
            "Mo",
            "Tu",
            "We",
            "Th",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    }
})
```

here is a demo with spanish month names -> **http://jsfiddle.net/r21747qc/**

Answer (score 43):

You can use **moment-with-locales.min.js** instead of **moment.min.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

and set localization before initializing daterangepicker

```
moment.locale('es');
$('#datePicker').daterangepicker();
```

Comment: it is very important to emphasis the word **instead**, if you load the both file `moment` and `moment-with-locales` this solution will NOT work. you have to **REPLACE** the `moment` with `moment-with-locales`. **DO NOT LOAD THEM BOTH**

Answer (score 4):

I made an 'pt-br' example based on @davidkonrad's comment

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
"locale": {
    "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    "separator": " - ",
    "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
    "fromLabel": "De",
    "toLabel": "Até",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "Dom",
        "Seg",
        "Ter",
        "Qua",
        "Qui",
        "Sex",
        "Sáb"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
        "Janeiro",
        "Fevereiro",
        "Março",
        "Abril",
        "Maio",
        "Junho",
        "Julho",
        "Agosto",
        "Setembro",
        "Outubro",
        "Novembro",
        "Dezembro"
    ],
    "firstDay": 0
}});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joaopedroraldi/d7bmppga/55

Comment: Sorry, the source of "moment.js" is now disabled. I updated and now is running.

Comment: still doesn't work... you are right, it looks like a problem with moment.js

Comment: Well, i fixed that day. They probably returned to the previous state. Now is working again.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Node

```
    var moment = require('moment');
    moment.locale('es');
    require('daterangepicker/daterangepicker');
```

Then set the options names as month and days names will be translated

```
$('#datePicker').daterangepicker({
    "locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
     }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('input[name="fecha_rango"]').daterangepicker({
   autoUpdateInput: false,
   format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
"locale": {

    "separator": " - ",
    "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
    "fromLabel": "DE",
    "toLabel": "HASTA",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "Dom",
        "Lun",
        "Mar",
        "Mie",
        "Jue",
        "Vie",
        "Sáb"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
        "Enero",
        "Febrero",
        "Marzo",
        "Abril",
        "Mayo",
        "Junio",
        "Julio",
        "Agosto",
        "Septiembre",
        "Octubre",
        "Noviembre",
        "Diciembre"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1
}});`